# Problema com um contador que soma números inseridos em C

Tags: c

Tenho que ler 6 valores e em seguida, mostrar quantos destes valores digitados foram positivos. Na próxima linha, deve mostrar a média de todos os valores positivos digitados, com um dígito após o ponto decimal.

O código está cumprindo todos os requisitos da questão, contudo não está retornando a média de todos os valores positivos digitados e não estou entendendo o motivo.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int counterNumPositivos, soma, counterEntradas;
    double numDigitado, media;
    soma = 0;
    counterNumPositivos = 0;
    counterEntradas = 0;
  
    while (counterEntradas <6){
       scanf("%lf", &numDigitado);
       counterEntradas += 1;
       soma += numDigitado;
       if (numDigitado >= 0)
           counterNumPositivos += 1;

}      
    media = soma / 6;
      
    printf("%d valores positivos\n", counterNumPositivos);
    printf("%.1f\n", media);

    return 0;
}
```

Estou quebrando a cabeça com algo que acredito que seja simples haha.

Answer (score 0):

### Onde está o problema?

Seu código tem 2 problemas:

1. Está adicionando à soma valores que também são negativos ou zero.
2. Está dividindo a soma por 6 e não por todos os número positivos.

### Como resolver?

Coloque a parte da soma dentro do `if`, dessa forma você só está somando os que são positivos. No final, divida pela quantidade de positivos e código vai funcionar como esperado:

```
while (counterEntradas <6){
    scanf("%lf", &numDigitado);
    counterEntradas += 1;
    if (numDigitado >= 0) {
        soma += numDigitado;
        counterNumPositivos += 1;
    }
}

media = soma / counterNumPositivos;
```

Comment: Corrigi aqui. Obrigado pela observação!

Comment: Se solucionei sua dúvida, não se esqueça de marcar como resposta no tick verde. Isso faz com que mais pessoas com a mesma dúvida que você possam encontrar com facilidade a solução do problema.